# Meaning of the negation in phrases like "не должен прочитать"

Tags: значения, выражения, глаголы, отрицание

I am often confused by phrases like "не должен прочитать," "не должен сделать," "не должен работать," "не должен платить" and so on. Sometimes the negation appears to refer to "должен," and sometimes - to the subsequent verb (i.e., to "прочитать" or whatever follows after "должен"). That is, I often get confused as to which interpretation is correct - "is not obliged to read" or "is obliged not to read."

**My question is this: Is there any simple rule or trick to determine which verb is implied to be negated in phrases like  "не должен прочитать"?**

There might be some rule I am not aware of. Or should I always assume that both interpretations are possible unless one of them is excluded by the context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually (usually), imperfective means "should not be doing it":

> Он не должен это читать // He cannot be required to be reading this

and perfective means "should be not doing it":

> Он не должен это прочитать // He is not allowed to read that.

Comment: Ohh, so the key is in the aspect (perfective vs imperfective)! I had no idea it could be that simple.

Comment: I just tried to recall numerous examples and feel that your rule is not universal. In particular, I recall something like "*он не должен сейчас быть в университете, потому что сегодня выходной день*." I now see two possible interpretations: (1) "He is not obliged to be in the university now, because today is a holiday." (2) "He is expected not to  be in the university now, because today is a holiday." I am confused... This verb "должен" is already extremely tricky by itself, and now this ambiguity with the negation adds insult to injury...

Comment: @Mitsuko: you're right, that's why I put the "usually" there twice.

Answer (score 1):

I would say - no trick needed. "(не должен) прочитать" has the same meaning as "должен (не прочитать)" - there is no differnce in result: you have an obligation to that book not to be read. There is no significant difference.

But if you want a rule - in general "is obliged not to read" is prefered in almoust any case ( when I translate Russuan to English I have to watch context of *English* phrase).

"Not obliged to read" should be translated to Russian as "не обязан читать"